# How to keep macro running when there are protected sheets?

Tags: vba, excel, validation

I have protected sheets 4 with a password because there are some cells that users aren't allowed to input in those cells in sheet 4. The password is 1234.

But, I want to run my macro, and if there is an error, the cell will be highlight automatically.

My macro doesn't run and error, because the cell that I want to highlight is in protected sheet.

How to make the sheet 4 stay protected and make my macro keep running when I click the validation button?

```
Private Sub commandbutton1_click()

FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled, Password:=1234, WriteResPassword:=1234, _
    ReadOnlyRecommended:=False, CreateBackup:=False

vehicle = Sheets("4").Range("K22")

expenditure_gasoline = Sheets("4").Range("M22")


If vehicle = true and expenditure_gasoline = 0 Then
        MsgBox "it should not be empty", vbcritical

End If

If vehicle = true and expenditure_gasoline = 0 Then Sheets("4").Range("M22").Interior.ColorIndex = 3


End sub
```

Comment: You need to unprotect the sheet before the chage (use `Sheets("4").Unprotect "1234"`), make the color update, then protect it back with `Sheets("4").Protect "1234"`, or just perform a one-time protection that will allow editing by VBA like this: **`Sheets("4")Protect Password:="1234", UserInterfaceOnly:=True`**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the changes bellow (untested)

---

**V1** - Protect the sheet from user changes, but not VBA changes `UserInterfaceOnly:=True`

---

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub commandbutton1_click()

    Const PATH_AND_FILENAME = "C:\YourTestFile.xlsx" '<------ Update this path & file name

    Dim wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet, vehicle As Variant, expenditureGasoline As Variant

    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=PATH_AND_FILENAME, WriteResPassword:="1234", _
                            Password:="1234", Format:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled)
    Set ws = wb.Sheets("4")

    ws.Protect Password:="1234", UserInterfaceOnly:=True '<--- Protect changes from UI only

    Set vehicle = ws.Range("K22")
    Set expenditureGasoline = ws.Range("M22")

    If Not IsError(vehicle) And Not IsError(expenditureGasoline) Then
        If vehicle = True And expenditureGasoline = 0 Then
            ws.Range("M22").Interior.ColorIndex = 3
            MsgBox "Cell M22 should not be empty", vbExclamation
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

---

**V2** - Unprotect before the change, and Protect back after the change

---

```
Private Sub commandbutton1_click()

    Const PATH_AND_FILENAME = "C:\YourTestFile.xlsx" '<------ Update this path & file name

    Dim wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet, vehicle As Variant, expenditureGasoline As Variant

    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=PATH_AND_FILENAME, WriteResPassword:="1234", _
                            Password:="1234", Format:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled)
    Set ws = wb.Sheets("4")
    Set vehicle = ws.Range("K22")
    Set expenditureGasoline = ws.Range("M22")

    If Not IsError(vehicle) And Not IsError(expenditureGasoline) Then
        If vehicle = True And expenditureGasoline = 0 Then

            ws.Unprotect "1234"                     '<--- Unprotect it before the change
            ws.Range("M22").Interior.ColorIndex = 3
            ws.Protect "1234"                       '<--- Protect it back, after the change

            MsgBox "Cell M22 should not be empty", vbExclamation
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```